# Joining multiple lists in a single row, without brackets or quotation marks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to store user input in different lists, then print them in a single line without brackets or quotation marks.

How do I print out more than one list in a single line while also keeping those conditions?

Printing them normally works, but it's not the result i'm looking for

```py
a = ['name']
b = ['name2']

print(f'Blahblah {a} {b}')
```

Which prints out: Blahblah ['name'] ['name2']

Printing a single list this way also works, but I haven't figured out how to add more than one list here

```py
a = ['name']
b = ['name2']

print('Blahblah %s' % ', ' .join(a))
```

Which prints out: Blahblah name

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can literally _add lists_: `a + b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the lists:

```
print('Blahblah %s' % (a + b))
```

Or use:

```
print('Blahblah %s' % [*a, *b])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace the `end` parameter in the print statement to achieve this.

if you do  `print("Hello", end='')`, this statement won't jump to next line after printing the output

eg:

```
print(a,end=' ')
print(b,end=' ')
```

you can even use loop if needed.

Answer (score 0):

With recent pythons,

```
print('Blahblah', *a, *b)
```

Gets close. But it is unclear if you want elements in the lists comma separated or not